# run yii action controller from another controller in different file

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Let's say I have a controller called `runAction()` in `file/test/backend/TestController`, but I want to run the action `runAction2` in `file/test/frontend/TestController2` (i want to run `runAction2()` in `runAction()`). How can i do so in yii2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. All I have to do is put the following code at the top of backend/TestController file.

```
use frontend/TestController2;
```

and to use a specific action in that controller i have to add the following in backend/TestController file:

```
runAction()
{
TestController2::runAction2()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in your

> frontend/config/main.php

add URL manager for access backend.

```
'components' => [
 'urlManagerbackend' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
                'baseUrl' => '/test/backend/',
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
  ],
]
```

after this create URL to action like below:

```
Yii::$app->urlManagerbackend->createUrl(['test/runAction2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to run another action is to use runAction method of the application

```
Yii::$app->runAction('controller/action', ['param'=>'value']);
```